# Couldn't arp for host, Kali Linux

Tags: security, kali-linux, ip, arp

I am currently learning the basics of cybersecurity and I am trying to follow the following tutorial on ARP spoofing. I am using kali linux on a VirtualBox VM on my Windows pc to redirect my windows computer's gateway to my kali VM and I keep getting the "Couldn't arp for host" error. I have also tried redirecting my iPhone's gateway to kali in case redirecting my computer would not make sense from a VM but I run into the same problem.
My full process is using ipconfig on windows to get something like (it's in French):

```
Carte réseau sans fil Wi-Fi :  
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : epfl.ch  
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .:  fe80::9c0c:82bd:c93d:a9ad%11  
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 128.179.179.227  
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0  
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 128.179.176.1
```

from which I deduce the commands I have to run on kali are:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
arpspoof -i eth0 -t 128.179.179.227 128.179.176.1
```

My phone's IP is 128.179.199.89.
When I run `ip a` on kali, I get that my IP address is 10.0.2.15 and gateway is 10.0.2.2, I don't know if this difference is the reason I cannot make my command work.
If anyone has any clue what I might be missing or what I should be calling instead, I'll be glad to hear your thoughts. Thank you!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mchrDyBdMmc&t=421s

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using wireless indeed but I will try with a wired connection.I don't know how to make sure the VM is bridged to the same network but I will try and look into it.

Comment: I was indeed, do you know how I can choose which bridge to select?

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting, you are wasting people's time: https://superuser.com/questions/1699753/couldnt-arp-for-host-kali-linux

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete my first post when I learnt about this forum :/

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are a couple of issues to address

- Your Kali VM is running with a NAT connection through your Host and to your target network. That must be changed to a Bridged connection so that your VM can get an IP address on the same network as your victim machine(s). This is controlled from the VitualBox management utility.
- You're using a wireless interface so you may not be able to create a working Bridge connection. Remove this area of potential confusion by using a wired interface instead if at all possible

Answer (score 1):

As roaima said, select bridged network, not NAT. Use a wired connection where possible.

You can see here how to set a VM to bridged networking:

https://wiki.dave.eu/index.php/VirtualBox_Network_Configuration

From that page:

[image: Attaching an adapter to bridged netword adapter:]

Changing the network interface to wired:

[image: Select the network interface]